# Getting the error "child exited with value 255" while executing the c++ application

Tags: c++

While executing my c++ application i am getting the error "child exited with value 255"

Any information regarding the same

Comment: What are you using to develop your application? In what context are you executing it?

Comment: We can't help you with error messages produced by your application. That doesn't look like an stdlibc error to me...

Comment: '255' seems to be a representation of (char) `-1`.

Comment: keep the door locked ???

Answer (score 0):

Sounds likely that wither your main application or a sub application isn't returning the correct error code. Does your main function end in a 'return 0;' or is it otherwise returning with some obscure number (such as 255, or -1)?